# How to convert an expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

**UPDATE**:

I'll try to explain what I mean.
There are 2 **different** classes (MyClass1 and MyClass2) and method to convert class1 to class2:

```
class MyClass1
  {
        //...Some fields and properties
 }

  class MyClass2
   {
        //...Some fields and properties
  }

public MyClass2 Convert(MyClass1 class1)
{
//.....
return class2Object;
}
```

There are 2 different  methods:

```
   void method1(Expression<Func<MyClass1, bool>> where, //other parameters)
    {
        //some operations
        //...............

        //need to call method2(Expression<Func<MyClass2, bool>>)
        //   BUT! How do I convert Expression<Func<MyClass1, bool>> 
        //   to Expression<Func<MyClass2, bool>>
    }

    void method2(Expression<Func<MyClass2, bool>> where, //other parameters)
    {
        //some operations
    }
```

How do I convert Expression< Func< **MyClass1**, bool>> to Expression< Func< **MyClass2**, bool > >

Comment: Since `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` cannot be converted into each other, how do you expect to convert the delegate?

Comment: Until you define explicit conversions between `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` you can't even get started.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't say how to convert between the two.

Comment: It doesn't matter how to convert  MyClass1 to MyClass2 . Just use a method ConvertFromClass1ToClass2().

Comment: Very rarely do I find anything that doesn't matter. The question is unanswerable without giving extended thought to your model, and any proposal could be far from scope of this question. Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, please help us answer your question by telling us exactly what you're trying to do.  We're always more able to help you when we have all the information.

Comment: There is no delegate instance in the example, btw; those are expression trees

Answer (score 7):

Let me guess what you are asking: Your `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` *look the same* (they both have an int field1 and a string field2). Now you have an `Expression<Func<MyClass1,bool>>`, something like:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass1, bool>> exp1 = x => x.field1 == 100; // x is MyClass1
```

And you want another expression, which *looks the same*, but it's for `MyClass2`:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass2, bool>> exp2 = x => x.field1 == 100; // x is MyClass2
```

If this is what you are asking, here is my answer:

To get the expression for `MyClass2`, you need to replace all `x` in `exp1`, because all `x` in exp1 are of type `MyClass1`. [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) is exactly what you want.

```
class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression NewParameterExp { get; private set; }

    public MyExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameterExp)
    {
        NewParameterExp = newParameterExp;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return NewParameterExp;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(MyClass1))
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(this.Visit(node.Expression), 
               typeof(MyClass2).GetMember(node.Member.Name).FirstOrDefault());
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

The visitor will go through(say "visit") the whole expression, visit all the nodes. When it comes to an `ParameterExpression` node, we change the node (because it's MyClass1, we change it to MyClass2, see VisitParameter method). Another thing we need to change is, when the visitor comes to a node like `x.field1`, it's visiting the field1 in `MyClass1`, we need to modify it too(see VisitMember). After going through the whole exp1, we get a totally new exp2, with some nodes replaced, that's what we want.

```
Expression<Func<MyClass1, bool>> exp1 = x => x.field1 == 100;

var visitor = new MyExpressionVisitor(Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass2), 
                        exp1.Parameters[0].Name));

var exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass2, bool>>
                (visitor.Visit(exp1.Body), visitor.NewParameterExp);

//the following is for testing
var data = new MyClass2();
Console.WriteLine(exp2.Compile()(data));  //False
data.field1 = 100;
Console.WriteLine(exp2.Compile()(data));   //True
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's something other than what I mean.

Comment: @Alex then how about describing what you mean?

Comment: @Alex: Can you give an example of the `Expression`?

Answer (score 1):

Expression trees are immutable, so to do this ou would need to walk the entire tree, rebuilding it and substiting any uses of the type with the equivalent - usually by writing a "visitor". When encountering a MemberExpression or MethodCallExpression, you would check the member's declaring type - if it is the one ou don't want, recreate it (Expression.PropertyOrField is useful here).

Note that you can't do this just at the places it is used; the entire tree must be regenerated. I'm not at a PC at the moment, but if you want I can do an example later; leave a comment if you need this example.

Note that this is somewhat complicated by the int/long and char/string mismatch.

Comment: Yes, please. Give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public CategoryViewModel GetSingle( Expression<Func<CategoryViewModel, bool>> where)
        {
            Expression<Func<DAL.EntityModels.Category, CategoryViewModel>> converter =
                c => ToBll(c);

            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DAL.EntityModels.Category), "category");
            var body = Expression.Invoke(where, Expression.Invoke(converter, param));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DAL.EntityModels.Category, bool>>(body, param);

            return  (CategoryViewModel )_categoryRepository.GetSingle(lambda);

        }

//..............
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return this.ObjectSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compile the first expression to a delegate and then convert it with
 [NJection.LambdaConverter](https://github.com/sagifogel/NJection.LambdaConverter) which is a library that converts delegates to expression trees.