# Linq expression type conversion

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Just two quick questions

1.What is the below statement called?

```
Func<usersDto, bool> predicate
```

2.How is it different from below?

```
Expression<Func<usersDto, bool>>
```

3.How do i convert `Func<type1,bool>` to `Func<type2,bool>`. Seems like advanced stuff me

**Example**

```
GetUsers(Func<UserDto,bool> predicate)
{    
  return EfContext.Users.Where ( convert above predicate to be passed here)
                        .Cast<>();       
}
```

Comment: question might have been answered already.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct

Comment: The first one is called predicate. The second one does not have a name, but I'm gonna call it Al.

Comment: @mdcuesta #2 answered from your link, #1 and #3 remains open

Comment: It's three questions, actually. You might want to split them into separate questions to better fit the Q&A format.

Comment: Oh, and statement #1 is called *variable declararation*

Comment: @DennisTraub `split them into separate questions` I would have been downvoted to oblivion that i cannot google for answers

Comment: Can you give an example of how #3 would be used?

Comment: Please give an example of a specific problem you're trying to solve.  The questions you've asked are virtually impossible to answer without some context.

Comment: @SWeko addded an example, basically the GetUsers method lies on Interface that will be called inside asp.net mvc controllers. Implementation will execute the predicate against Entity Framework Context which has another type `Users`. I want to run the predicate that Interface gets to the entity framework context entities

Comment: Couldn't your `GetUsers` method take a `Func<User,bool>` parameter instead of `Func<usersDto, bool>`?

Comment: @phoog But then i will be executing against a User Entity. No separation of concerns, i would be hard to track down from where the UserEntity is modified

Comment: Possible duplicate (in more than one ways): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065401/linq-expression-type-conversion

Comment: @Deeptechtons in that case, and assuming that the User entity and the userDto have a common interface, you could probably take an `Expression<Func<userDto, bool>>`, and create an expression visitor that constructs an equivalent `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` that you can pass to the EF context.  Danny Chen's link explains that.

Comment: @DennisTraub huh?  How is it useful to say that a question is a duplicate of itself?

Comment: @phoog wrong link, I meant this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065671/linq-expression-conversion-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Func<T, TResult>` is a built-in delegate that takes a parameter whose type is `T` and returns a value whose type is `TResult`. In your question, `predicate` is a delegate takes an instance of `usersDto` and returns a `bool`.

An `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` is a *uncompiled* `Func<T, TResult>`, it can be analyzed, or  packed into another expression as a part.

Q3: see [my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5133473/323924).