# Convert IQueryable to URL query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to perform inter micro services communication with DDD repository, the repository can either query the local database or call the remote micro service rest API for data. I need to convert the IQueryable to query string in order to  call the rest API with the following:

1. filter
2. orderBy
3. pagination
4. select

Anyone has done this before?

Comment: Can you give an example of that you are trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224696/how-to-implement-custom-linq-provider-for-decorator)?

Comment: Did you have a look at OData or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api)